# window popstate event is not triggering in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, popstate

I want to detect the backbutton click event so am using window popstate event in jquery. but it is not at all firing in any time.

please refer below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).on("popstate",function(){
                debugger
            });
        });
```

tried this way too.

```
   window.onpopstate = function(event) {debugger
        alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
    };
```

is there any external script need to add for that ? or anything else need to confiure in my page.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind an event listener with javascript like this:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    alert( "triggered" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks.it is native javscript  why jquery one not triggering

Comment: need to refer any external script  ?

Comment: could you make it in fiddle and share it me ?

Comment: when it will be triggered ? when clicking on back button right ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need add first an history before detect back?
Example:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "?foo=1");
```